# C#-Selenium - Windows file upload window freezing

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing

There is an automation test method (C# Selenium, using microsoft`s UnitTesting) where I need to upload file. I'm trying it with below code. 
Problem is as soon as it pastes the file path the window freezes, before hitting 'Enter'. I know this is not a new problem, but I failed to get a proper solution for my problem.

Code:

```
fileBrowseButton.Click();//This opens up windows file upload window
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(CompleteFilePath, false, 2, 2000);
SendKeys.SendWait("^{V}");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
```

Comment: Check if you have `input` with `type='file'` attribute and you can use the send_keys to upload the file directly rather using the clipboard approach.

Comment: @supputuri - Window is freezing because of clipboard action?

Comment: I can't comment on that without much information, as we don't know which method is freezing the execution.

Comment: Can you check `fileBrowserButton` html, there should be an `<input type='file'`..

Answer (score 0):

You can try another way to upload a file:

Send the file you want to upload directly to the element with the "type = file" attribute on the page you are on.

As an example:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@tyle='file']").SendKeys("abc.jpg")
```